# Cannot get mod_deflate to work

Tags: mod-deflate

I Cant seem to get mod_deflate to work. I tried using httpd.conf and htaccess with no luck. this is my htaccess code:

```
# DEFLATE compression
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Set compression for: html,txt,xml,js,css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
# Deactivate compression for buggy browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Set header information for proxies
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
# END DEFLATE
```

I checked that the module is installed and configured what else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

it miss the `SetOutputFilter`

```
# MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript  application/x-httpd-php

# DEFLATE NOT COMPATIBLE BROWERS
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```